# How should I include other jsp files in a jsp file and why?

Tags: java, jsp

So there seems to be a few ways to include jsp files in jsp files, being:

```
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
<jsp:include page="header.jsp" />
<c:import url="header.jsp" />
<tagfiles:tagfile />
```

So which one should I use and why? What advantages / disadvantages do they come with?

Comment: Why the !'^+!'^+ are you down-voting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The include directive, makes a copy of the included page and copies it into a JSP page (the "including page") during translation. This is known as a `static include` (or translate-time include) and uses the following syntax:

```
<%@ include file="/jsp/userinfopage.jsp" %>
```

**Two alternatives exist for the dynamic include**

The jsp:include tag, described in "Standard Actions: JSP Tags", dynamically includes output from the included page within the output of the including page during execution. This is known as a `dynamic include` (or runtime include) and uses the following syntax:

```
<jsp:include page="/jsp/userinfopage.jsp" flush="true" />
<c:import url="header.jsp" />
```

Unlike `jsp:include`, the `c:import` action provides a mechanism to access resources that can be specified through a URL, thus allowing page authors to get access to resources that reside outside the Web application. On the other hand, it lacks the ability to flush the response. Finally, `c:impor`t is comparatively more `heavyweight` and is therefore not appropriate when a lightweight solution is sought.

`tagfiles` are basically templates, which are like generic and can render some common views, but internally they will themselves use html tags itself.but not much of use while including jsp pages.

Answer (score 0):

In my Project, I have used following approach

```
<jsp:include page="header.jsp" />
```

I have used this for loading specific div element instead of refreshing whole page.
This can be done by using JQuery's load method.

Including JSP file allows us to reuse the template in many places. Just write template code in JSP file and use it wherever required.

JSP page directives works at translation time while standerd actions works at run time.

You can tagfiles for calling functions on server side. You can also use tagfiles for creation of templates.